# sunflowerplot legend symbol with the correct number of segment

Tags: r, graphics, legend

I wish create a good legend for a `sunflowerplot` in R with the symbol of multiple leaves with the correct number of "`petals`".

The "`petals`" was created in the function `sunflowerplot` by segments with different angles.
It is possible to recreate a figure with some segments but do you know if it's possible to insert a self created symbol in a legend? Or have you find a solution to create a legend symbol with the different levels of `petals` draw in the plot for the `sunflowerplot` function.

```
dat <- structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0.074, 0.074, 0.074, 0.22, 0.22, 0.22, 0.66, 
 0.66, 0.66, 18, 19, 19, 19, 19, 18, 16, 16, 18, 3, 3, 3), .Dim = c(12L, 
 2L))
sunflowerplot(dat[, 1], dat[, 2])
legend("right", c("1 rep", "4 rep", "8 rep"), pch = c(16, 3, 8))
```

I know it is possible to use `pch 4` and `8` in the legend but I am not really agree with this method.

Answer (score 0):

Ok My solution is to don't use the `sunflowerplot` function, but to create my own function inspired of the sunflowerplot code.

step 1 : calculate the number of point for each coordinate

> tt <- xyTable(cbind(dat[,1], dat[,2]))

step 2: plot the tt object

> plot(tt$x, tt$y, cex = tt$number, pch = 16)

step 3: add the legend only for existing points

> legend("topright", pt.cex = sort(unique(tt$number)), pch = rep(16, length(unique(tt$number))), legend = paste(sort(unique(tt$number)), "replic.", sep = " "), bty = "n")